# Google Cloud Functions - permission-denied vs failed-precondition

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Which HTTPs error type should I use when checking that the auth id is present?

```
const userId = context.auth.token.uid;

if (!userId) {
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
    "failed-precondition",
    "Authentication required."
  );
}
```

or

```
const userId = context.auth.token.uid;

if (!userId) {
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
    "permission-denied",
    "Authentication required."
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can choose the error type you prefer among the [list of available  error types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/common_providers_https#functionserrorcode). As a matter of fact, this error code is going to be sent back to your front-end, which you normally control.

Now, looking at the list of error codes...

> `permission-denied`: The caller does not have permission to execute
> the specified operation.
>
> `failed-precondition`: Operation was rejected because the system is
> not in a state required for the operation's execution.

... I would choose `permission-denied`.